# Different result when using groupByKey() locally and on a cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I have a `RDD[(DenseVector[Int], String)]`, DenseVector is a collection used in [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) and I will call it `DV` in my snippets. Let us use a simple one `moon = [(DV(4), "Tinker"), (DV(2), "Tailor"), (DV(4), "Soldier"), (DV(2), "Sailor"), (DV(2), "Poor Man"), (4), "Rich Man")]`. I am grouping it by key using `moon.groupByKey()` locally and then saving it as a text file, the result is:

```
(DV(4), CompactBuffer("Tinker", "Soldier", "Rich Man")), (DV(2), CompactBuffer("Tailor", "Sailor", "Poor Man"))
```

I am then using the same code but using a Spark cluster composed of two slaves by using my master URL instead of `local`. The result is then composed of two files, part-00000:

```
(DV(4), CompactBuffer("Tinker")), (DV(2), CompactBuffer("Tailor")), (DV(4), CompactBuffer("Soldier")),
```

And part-00001:

```
(DV(2), CompactBuffer("Sailor")), (DV(2), CompactBuffer("Poor Man")), (DV(4), CompactBuffer("Rich Man"))
```

Is there a reason explaining this behavior, why `groupByKey()` is not able to group by key when using it not on a cluster? I am using Spark 2.0.0.

Comment: huh? what happens if you `coalesce(1, false)` on the cluster?

Comment: Interesting, I get one file that has the same content as a merge of part-00000 and part-00001. So it does not work even when I coalesce the RDD.

Comment: I think it is working - but it might be the way the file is saved - the problem is I cannot recreate this. You can try to reduceByKey and see what happens.

Comment: OK so I just changed the type of my key, I simplified my code for the question but I was using a type from a library. I used an integer instead and it now works perfectly. But why is it working locally?